# How to fill blank cell2 with value from cell1 on tabbing into it in Excel?

Tags: excel, copy, tabbing

I need to fill a blank cell say D7 with value from A2 on tabbing into it with a NON vba solution.

Been trying to figure it out but having no luck.

Thanks

Comment: If D7 is truly blank (no value, no formula) then there wont be a way to do it without VBA. Even if there was a formula in D7 I dont beleive theres a way to have it appear blank when its not in focus.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all Worksheet.ActivateEvent Events are handled by C# or VB. Such as

`Sub Worksheet1_ActivateEvent() Handles Me.ActivateEvent
    MsgBox(Me.Name & " was activated.")
    End Sub`

Unfortunately there is no way around it. Does your solution need to stay entirely in Excel?

Comment: Thanks everyone, now I now not to keep trying

Comment: Good luck, here is the MSDN documentation on Excel C# and VB functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj227887.aspx